# Passing member values between almost identical structs

Tags: c++, struct, member

I wonder if someone has a solution to the following problem, I have two almost identical structs, and I need to pass the values from struct A to struct B and they have difference of one member.

Example looks something like this that I have these structs:

```
struct insideA
{
double C1;
double C2;
int C3;
str C4;
};

struct insideB
{
int D3;
str D4;
};   

struct A
{
insideA inA; 
double c;
std::string d;
} a;

struct B
{
insideB inB;
double c;
std::string d;
} b;
```

Now that the structs A and B are almost similar but not exactly and if we imagine that the b is populated, I can easily pass the values member by member followingly:

```
a.inA.C3 = b.inB.D3;
a.inA.C4 = b.inB.D4;
a.c = b.c;
a.d = b.d;
```

And now a has all the information that b had and I can populate the other members of a. So my problem is that I have to do this about 30 or 40 times with different structs, where only the first member of the struct changes, so is there any better method for doing this than passing the values struct member of a to struct member of b individually?

Comment: make one base class containing the same members and implement copying. "Almost identical" wont help you much

Comment: can you modify the existing structure definitions?

Comment: No, I cannot edit the existing structure, because it is in a driver and I can't access the source code :(

Answer (score 1):

Let's use templates!

```
template <struct Inside>
struct AorB
{
  Inside in; 
  double c;
  std::string d;

  template <struct OtherInside>
  AorB& operator=(const AorB<OtherInside>& that) {
    in = that.in;
    c = that.c;
    d = that.d;
  }
};

struct A : AorB<insideA>
{
  template <struct OtherInside>
  A& operator=(const AorB<OtherInside>& that) {
    AorB<insideA>::operator=(that);
    return *this;
  }
};

struct B : AorB<insideB> 
{
  template <struct OtherInside>
  B& operator=(const AorB<OtherInside>& that) {
    AorB<insideB>::operator=(that);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

You can extend this idea to the inside classes as well.

Comment: Hey,

thank you for your fast reply, I tried to carefully describe my problem but I forgot to clarify that between all the different structs that I have to pass, each of them the "body" members are different, so with this method I would need to do need to do a similar solution for each of them and then see which template to use in which case. I thought if there was a way to automate that somehow